# Where can I find/ask about restrictions at airports for photographing?

Tags: permission, airplanes

I had my camera with me the other day and was going to use my lunch break to take some photos at the local airport of landings and takeoffs. However with the security concerns that seem to always be present, I was not sure if this was wise and decided not to at the last moment.

Does anyone know how to find out if it is okay to photograph at airports/runways (outside the fence of course)? Or procedures on which personnel you should attempt to contact before doing so to keep yourself from being detained for questioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right to be cautious, though I'm sure the situation is not as bad as I think!

I would sign up to the forums at airliners.net - there are so many really talented photographers on that site, they must know the situation better than anyone else!

http://www.airliners.net

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to be a good place, even found an open thread about someone who actually had a run in, and lots of posts with information on rights and attitudes. That helps a lot!

Comment: http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/aviation_photography/read.main/368535/ For those that are curious.

Answer (score 1):

Airports are classes as high security areas these days so casual photography tends to be frowned upon. If you call the airport directly and explain the situation they will be able to give you the number of their press/media department who would be able to arrange permission for you take photos within the airport but its probably going to involve you being security checked and you could well have to pay for that. If you only want to take photos from outside the airport grounds then although its legal to do you may get hassled by the police. Even for this it is best to contact the airports media/press office first just to cover your self.

Comment: Makes sense, I personally care more about the runway and air traffic, but I did leave the question open for both to keep it general. +1 from me.